# How to pass array variable from view to controller in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to pass the variable from view to controller I am using ajax call to achieve it i am getting the error below. I don't know what i am missing here.

> WARN 41440 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

This is my code

```
document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function(){
  var selchbox = getSelectedChbox(this.form);     // gets the array returned by getSelectedChbox()
  myvalue = JSON.stringify(selchbox);
 //document.write("check check"+selchbox);
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UserController/delete",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {key:myvalue},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
                     alert("Are you sure?");
                 },
                 error: function (args) {
                     alert("Error on ajax post");
                 }

    });
  alert(selchbox);
}
```

My controller method looks like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String delete(@RequestBody String key) {
    System.out.println("My Array value"+key.toString());
    return key;
}
```

What i am missing here? Any Help

Comment: What does `{sORGID}` in your mapping means?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i could able to pass the values from my view to controller I am posting the code. 
This is my js code

```
document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function(){
  var selchbox = getSelectedChbox(this.form);     // gets the array returned by getSelectedChbox()
var myvalue = JSON.stringify(selchbox);
 //document.write("check check"+selchbox);
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/delete",
        dataType : "JSON",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(selchbox),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
                     alert("Are you sure?");
                 },
                 error: function (args) {
                     alert("Error on ajax post");
                 }

    });
  alert(selchbox);
}
```

And my controller code

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String delete(@RequestBody String value){
     System.out.println("My Array value"+value.toString());
     return value;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

At leaset two problems

1. url: "UserController/delete" in your ajax won't match "/delete/{sORGID}" in your controller.
2. data: {key:myvalue} in your ajax, the property name is key, in your controller it's myvalue[], this should also be the same.

Comment: @SKH you can post the error message here.  the warn 41440 is not the error

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to delete, why not use the verb delete http?

I think you are not using the correct parameter: RequestParam is used to map your sORGID parameter to the URL (a parameter you did not use on the client side, you must use it or delete it). 
If you want to map Json, you must use @RequestBody.

I hope it helps

Comment: I want to delete the selected checkbox value from db as well. In my js function "selchbox " is returning the selected checkbox value i am trying to pass this value to controller to perform delete action

Comment: @SKH So you send a json to your backend. To read it you need to change your annotation RequestParam to RequestBody. But you still will have a problem because the other parameter sORGID in your controller is not set in your js. Your url should looks like UserController/delete/mysORGID in your js. (BTW  are you sure this is the correct url? )

Comment: I have edited the controller code as mentioned by you. Yes the url is correct(UserController is the controller name and delete is the method declared in the controller)

Comment: By default, it does not use the controller name for the URL. Did you explicitly put a RequestMapping on your controller with the value "UserController"?